# Creating iOS SHA1 Hash with UTF-8 characters

Tags: objective-c, hash, utf-8

I'm using this code to create **hash** from giving string  to devolving **IOS** App.

```
-(NSString*) sha1:(NSString*)input
{
 const char *cstr = [input cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cstr length:input.length];

 uint8_t digest[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

 CC_SHA1(data.bytes, data.length, digest);

 NSMutableString* output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];

 for(int i = 0; i < CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
 [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];

 return output;

}
```

my PHP code is

```
 sha1(json_encode($array));
```

I have string that contain **Arabic** languages.

when I create hash from **English** string and compare it with hash created from **php** code under Ubuntu**strong text** the result will be the same.

but when I create the hash with **Arabic** character it will and compare it with  hash created from php code does't mach the result.

so what is the man problem  with this code.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post php code for creating hash?

Comment: input.length is the number of characters in the string, not the number of bytes in the UTF8-encoded data representation.  You are likely truncating your string when you convert it into the NSData.  Try using -[NSString dataUsingEncoding:] instead

Comment: yes sure :  return sha1(json_encode($array));

Comment: Mr.iccir are you mean to replace  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cstr length:input.length]; with  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cstr length:[NSString dataUsingEncoding:]];

Answer (score 4):

`input.length` is the number of characters, not the number of bytes, the difference is that many bytes under UTF8 encoding are multiple bytes in length.

Replace:

```
const char *cstr = [input cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cstr length:input.length];
```

with the NSString method:

```
NSData *data = [input  dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

There is no need for the intermediate `const char *cstr`.

Comment: Are you sure that the php is using UTF8 encoding? Perhaps it is using UTF16 -- or another encoding. Try and display the actual bytes in the php Arabic string.

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem that come from my **PHP json_encode($array)** function.

so I found this function in http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php  that encode my json with **UTF-8** character

```
function my_json_encode($arr)
{
    //convmap since 0x80 char codes so it takes all multibyte codes (above ASCII 127). So such characters are being "hidden" from normal json_encoding
   array_walk_recursive($arr, function (&$item, $key) { if (is_string($item)) $item = mb_encode_numericentity($item, array (0x80, 0xffff, 0, 0xffff), 'UTF-8'); });
   return mb_decode_numericentity(json_encode($arr), array (0x80, 0xffff, 0, 0xffff), 'UTF-8');

 }
```

EX:

**sha1(my_json_encode($newArray)**